# socket with python flask and ajax call

Tags: python-3.x, flask, socket.io, flask-security, flask-session

I have scenario where I want to use sockets to wrap my API calls and not available to hit directly the api in browser and get data.

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Report</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="background-color:mintcream;">
<div ><span style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: x-large;al:center;">reportyu</span> <br> <br>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Lame</th>
                <th>IAr</th>
                <th>Hee</th>
                <th>ED</th>
                <th>SPs</th>
                <th>Ts</th>
                <th>SD</th>
                <th>Rs</th>
                <th>Ld</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
               <th>Lame</th>
                <th>IAr</th>
                <th>Hee</th>
                <th>ED</th>
                <th>SPs</th>
                <th>Ts</th>
                <th>SD</th>
                <th>Rs</th>
                <th>Ld</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
<script>
function setupData() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/index_get_data",
                "dataType": "json",
                "dataSrc": "data",
                "contentType":"application/json"
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "L_name"},
                {"data": "Ia_r"},
                {"data": "He_e"},
                {"data": "e_d",
                    "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        $(nTd).html("<a href='//abc.app.com/"+oData.e_d+"'>"+oData.e_d+"</a>");
                    }
                },
                {"data": "s_ps"},
                {"data": "t_s"},
                {"data": "s_d",
                    "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        $(nTd).html("<a href='//app2.com/"+oData.s_d+"'>"+oData.s_d+"</a>");
                    }
                },
                {"data": "R_n",
                    "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        $(nTd).html("<a href='//sshse.com/"+oData.R_n+"'>"+oData.R_n+"</a>");
                    }
                },
                {"data": "l_d"}

            ],
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        orientation: 'landscape',
                        pageSize: 'LEGAL'
                    },
                    'copyHtml5',
                    'excelHtml5'
        ]
        });

    });
}
$( window ).on( "load", setupData );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my app.py :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/index_get_data')
def stuff():
  # Assume data comes from somewhere else
  with open('crtp.json') as test_file:
    data = json.load(test_file)
  return jsonify(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

This works as expected but when I hit the url `localhost:5000` in browser I am also able to see the API call in `network tab` of the browser and then if I hit the endpoint `localhost:5000/index_get_data`
I am able to use the API openly.
I have explored options of sending `token based auth` in headers and `basic auth` but still the response can be derived and the API is still open for use which I want to restrict , I came across `flask-sockets` which seems to help here but not sure how can I implement this here.

Any help regarding this or any other approach to achieve this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you really are trying to do, and why you don't want 'browsers' to be able to see your endpoints. Flask (and browsers) use HTTP and HTTPS to communicate. There are huge amounts of information, packages, etc about how all that works - and if you are interested in any sort of interoperability - you should stick to well-established protocols. You might be asking how to SECURE your endpoints such that only clients that have appropriate credentials can access your site. That is what packages such as Flask-Security-Too, Flask-Dance, Flask-Login all provide. Flask itself doesn't provide any endpoint protection

Comment: you did not understand the problem then.
I am trying to use sockets here in flask how can I achieve this in this case ?